# Component. set value is not passing to the Helper Method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

It might be an old question. How to pass the map value to the Aura component helper method without modifying the function parameter in the controller(helper.testCall)

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="exampleMap" type="Map" default="{}"/>
<lightning:button label="Test Helper Method" onclick="{!c.testButtonClick}"/ </aura:component>
```

**Controller Method**

```
({
testButtonClick : function(component, event, helper) {
      let map = new Map();
       map.set('key1','value1');
       map.set('key2','value2');
    
     component.set("v.exampleMap",map);
    //Is it possible to pass the map value to testCall without changing the parameter 
    helper.testCall(component, event, helper);
}})
```

Javascript:

```
({
testCall : function(component, event, helper) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.exampleMap")));
} })
```

**map shows the value {}**

TestApp

```
  <aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="force:slds" >
  <c:Lg_Comp1></c:Lg_Comp1>
 </aura:application>
```

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, maps do not properly `JSON.stringify`.

Try this in NodeJS, your browser's dev console, etc:

```
const map = new Map();
map.set('message','Hello World');
console.log(map.get('message')); // Hello World
console.log(JSON.stringify(map)); // {}
```

You'll see the message is stored, but the map doesn't serialize its values. This is just a quirk of how maps are implemented in JavaScript versus how `JSON.stringify` chooses which parts of an object it can stringify.

Instead, you'd have to manually convert the map into an actual object before using JSON.stringify. That might look like this:

```
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(
  Object.fromEntries(
    [...map.keys()].map(
      key=>[key, map.get(key)]
    )
  )
);
```

Where `[...value]` takes an Array-like object and changes to a proper array, `Array.map` converts the values in an array to a different array, `key=>[key, map.get(key)]` is an arrow function that converts each key in the map to a key-value array, and `Object.fromEntries` takes an array of key-value arrays and converts them into an object.

I realize that this is probably a lot to unpack, so I'd recommend doing some research on the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) for more information on these topics.

Comment: Thank you so much, How can I get the value in JavaScript helper side without passing parameter. Could you please explain me that in your answer

Comment: Do we need use call back function for this or any other solution

Comment: @Annappa No, the data is there, you just can't JSON.stringify it. Try `alert(JSON.stringify([...component.get('v.exampleMap').entries()]))`

Comment: thank you. Take care